# chromium does not open PDFs

Tags: pdf, chromium

i use chromium 5.0.375.70 (on ubuntu 10.04) and it cannot open the PDFs in browser window, it always **makes me save** them. is there a solution to this?
(i do not want to use *google docs* to view, just my default viewer which is evince)

Answer (score 1):

you should install mozplugger. after that restart the browser and it should work.
you can install mozplugger through synaptic or with

```
sudo apt-get install mozplugger
```

[mozplugger documentation](http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/documentation.html)

despite the name mozplugger also works with other browsers like chrome.

**EDIT:**

i found the following links:

- [issue 19587](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19587)
- [issue 22715](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22715)
- [issue 22065](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22065)

apparently the mozplugger solution does not work because of a bug. you have to wait until this is resolved or install the google docs view extension as a workaround.

**EDIT:**

regarding to this [site](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/) the internal pdf support should work under linux (latest dev version).

Comment: Is there a workaround?